# Login scripts - Powerpoint

Tags: batch-file, powerpoint, login-script, powerpoint-2007

I have a simple login script that will pull another .bat where it will point to our powerpoint template.

Problem is, whenever I use the below, I always get a popup on the second instance which is meant to be hidden, as you can see `-y` doesn't hide it. I've tried a min before `xcopy` but that causes errors and my knowledge of this is rather limited.

Below is the code:

login script:

```
@echo off
REM Copy Powerpoint default template to user profile

xcopy "\\wsfile01\AppData\Microsoft Office Templates\Blank.potx" "\\nebula\public\Ldn_town\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates" /Y 

exit
```

I appreciate that we are copying from network to network and this may seem daft but all our profiles sit on a local server for each satellite office.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This is confusing... please accept my edit and clean up your question to make it clearer what you are trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a Y to the xcopy command via `echo` which will simulate entering Y yourself.

```
@echo off
echo y | xcopy "\\wsfile01\AppData\Microsoft Office Templates\Blank.potx" "\\nebula\public\Ldn_town\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates"
```

Answer (score 0):

For copying a single file usually `copy` is used instead of `xcopy` as when executed from within a batch file the target file is automatically overwritten, except the target file has read-only attribute set.

```
@copy "\\wsfile01\AppData\Microsoft Office Templates\Blank.potx" "\\nebula\public\Ldn_town\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates"
```

In case of target file already exists with read-only attribute set, usage of command `xcopy` with the parameters `/R /Y` is better.

```
@xcopy "\\wsfile01\AppData\Microsoft Office Templates\Blank.potx" "\\nebula\public\Ldn_town\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates" /I /R /Y
```